# How to override a Laravel package, without editing the original files?

Tags: laravel, controller, package

I'm trying to edit a Laravel package in my project. But i should edit file without editing the original files. Like wordpress, create a copy of the Controller, Service Provider etc.. and edit them in my folder and not in the original vendor folder.

Is there a procedure to follow to achieve this? Or if I have to make various changes should I uninstall the package and do everything by hand so that I have full control?

The package is `harimayco/wmenu-builder` and i want to edit the controllers.

Any advices?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Based on **my personal experience**

```
1) I fork it in github
2) Edit it to fit my requirements
3) Load it in my composer.json
```

For more details : ["Composer: Using your own fork for a package"](https://snippets.khromov.se/composer-use-your-own-fork-for-a-package/)

Comment: Thanks, now I try. But i have a question. This fork create a vendor package with a copy of the original package.. does this mean that i can edit the vendor folder that is created?

Comment: Yes, you can edit it as a separate tiny project, then push it into Github when you done, and composer will pull the changes for you when you run `composer update` command

Comment: Ok and when the original package will update how can i do with my forked package? Thanks

Comment: When the original package get updated you may sync your fork  to keep it up-to-date with the upstream repository.
See more [here](https://help.github.com/en/github/collaborating-with-issues-and-pull-requests/syncing-a-fork)